# change ip address and webserver breaks

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws

I am using AWS and have an ubuntu instance with nginx installed, when I create an image and create a new instance, or give it an elastic IP the webserver stops working. Same thing with apache. The security group is fine, and it was working, I assign a different IP and it stops, I can't access it at that ip or any other, but I can ssh in. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the default site was pointed at a wordpress site and since all the configs are stored in the db is was redirecting to an old ip